# How can I access functions of Client.coffee from MVC4 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, coffeescript

I am using MVC4 and I have a file Client.coffee which have many functions. I am new to coffee JavaScript so want to know how can i access those functions from view.

Answer (score 0):

CoffeeScript wraps your code in an anonymous function `(function () { /* code here /* })();`. To make your function in your coffee source file visible from other file, you can export those function to the `window` object (or some other existing global object). So, instead of defining function as:

```coffee
some_func = (a, b, c) -> blabla
```

You can write

```coffee
window.some_func = (a, b, c) -> blabla
```

Or you can group them in a global hash:

```coffee
window.global_funcs =
    some_func: (a) -> bla
    some_func2: (b, c) -> blabla

# call with
global_funcs.some_func('param_1')
```

If you are using CommonJS, you can export the functions to `exports`. And the existence operator `?` might be helpful

```coffee
global = exports ? window
global.some_func = (a) -> bla
```